# Java Socket and ServerSocket not communicating

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

self explainatory, server handle the client and recognize the connection, but they can't communicate yet. here's the code:

Server Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Server{
    private final int PORT=8080;
    public BufferedReader fromClient;
    public PrintWriter toClient;
    public ServerSocket server;
    public Socket clientSocketHandler;
    public Server(){ //constructor

        if(startServer())
            System.out.println("Server Avviato...");
        else
            System.out.println("Errore nell'avvio del server...");
    }

    private boolean startServer(){
        try{
            server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void runServer(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Server in ascolto sulla porta " + PORT + " ...");
            clientSocketHandler = server.accept();
            System.out.println("Client Connesso...");

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(clientSocketHandler.getInputStream());
            fromClient = new BufferedReader(isr);

            OutputStreamWriter osr = new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocketHandler.getOutputStream());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(osr);
            toClient = new PrintWriter(bw);


        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

MainServer Class:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MainServer{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Server s1 = new Server();
        s1.runServer();

        float n1,n2;
        String op;

        try{
            s1.toClient.println("comunicazione da server");
            System.out.println("Aspettando i numeri...");
            n1=Float.parseFloat(s1.fromClient.readLine());
            n2=Float.parseFloat(s1.fromClient.readLine());
            System.out.println("Numeri accettati");

            System.out.println("Aspettando operatore...");
            op=s1.fromClient.readLine();
            System.out.println("Operatore accettato");
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



}
```

Client class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client{
    private final int PORT=8080;
    private InetAddress address = InetAddress.getLoopbackAddress();
    public PrintWriter toServer;
    public BufferedReader fromServer;
    public BufferedWriter bw;
    public Socket client;

    public Client(){
        if(startClient())
            System.out.println("Connesso al Server...");
        else
            System.out.println("Errore nella connessione...");
    }

    private boolean startClient(){
        try{
            client = new Socket(address, PORT); 

            OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream());
            bw = new BufferedWriter(osw);
            toServer = new PrintWriter(bw);

            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream());
            fromServer = new BufferedReader(isr);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

MainClient Class:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainClient{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        Client c = new Client();

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader kBoard = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String n1,n2,op;

        try{
            System.out.println(c.fromServer.readLine());
            System.out.println("Inserisci il primo numero");
            n1=kBoard.readLine();

            System.out.println("Inserisci il Secondo numero");
            n2=kBoard.readLine();

            System.out.println("Passando i valori al server");
            c.toServer.println(n1);
            c.toServer.println(n2);

            System.out.println("Inserisci l'operatore [+,-,/,*]");
            op = kBoard.readLine();

            System.out.println("Passando i valori al server");
            c.toServer.println(op);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

Sorry for the italian Strings.
It client stucks at "Connesso al Server..." and Server stucks at "Aspettando i numeri"

Help me!! :)

Answer (score 0):

- You should make a infinite loop (`while(true) {...}`) in the server socket method `runServer` in order to accept client sockets. Without it just doesn't listens!
- In order to process more than one client you should also make it multi-threading; i.e. each time a new client is accepted launch a new thread to process the request.

Should help you out. Have a nice day...

Comment: It isn't a problem of connection, server and client do connect but they doesn't communicate.